# open_basedir restriction Error with CodeIgniter App in Subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, plesk, open-basedir

I have a CodeIgniter Application for Administration purposes, put in a Subdirectory of the domain.

I get the following error when I update a record and try to clear the cached copy of the page, which resides in the Cache folder in domain root.

My server have Plesk control panel and I have tried modifying the vhost.conf and restarted the server but the problem still stays...

First of all I cannot understand why a php script in a subdirectory cannot access a folder in the root, is this because of CodeIgniter?

Please help... Following is the Error I receive.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: unlink(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../../cache/2dd676d5e044a6190d27ccbaf094db7b.html) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/:/tmp/)

Filename: models/products_model.php

Line Number: 180
```

Comment: Did you search for the error message and try to solve it?

Comment: Yes doing it for 4 5 hours... Tried so many things. At first the CI app was in a subdomain and I thought it might work if I put it into a subdirectory, but the error is still there. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

do you actually have 'open_basedir' allowed on your server? It can often be turned off - and would generate this sort of error...

Comment: The same routine is working absolutely fine in another PHP script.

Comment: does that routine access the same file/directory?

Comment: It's like whenever user make some changes the script removes the static html cached copy so the changes are registered, and it works.

Now I have made this administration app and it's in the subdirectory of the same domain, and when I edit a record and tries to the remove the cached file, this error appears.

I am confused how php disallow a script in the same subdirectory. Does this have anything to do with CodeIgniter?

Comment: no - it is not a codeigniter problem. it seems like a problem with opendir() and the access privilages in the subdomain (or perhaps the path to the subdomain) - which is why it is not working

Comment: The CodeIgniter App is in the SubDirectory, not the Subdomain.